# Mysql erro 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

```
-- 1 --
create database clinica;
use clinica;

-- 2 --
create table ambulatorio(
idnroa int(15) unsigned not null auto_increment,
andar int(15) not null,
capacidade smallint(45) not null,
primary key (idnroa)
);

create table medicos(
idcodm int(15) unsigned not null auto_increment,
idnroa int(15) unsigned not null ,
nome varchar(40) not null,
idade smallint(15) not null,
especialidade char(20)  not null,
cpf numeric(11) not null,
cidade varchar(30) not null,
nroa int(15) not null, 
primary key (idcodm),
foreign key (idnroa) references ambulatorio (idnroa)
);

create table pacientes(
idcodp int(15) unsigned not null auto_increment,
nome varchar(40) not null,
idade smallint(15) not null,
cidade char(30) not null,
cpf numeric(11) not null,
primary key (idcodp)
);

create table funcionarios(
idcodf int(15) unsigned not null auto_increment,
nome varchar(40) not null,
idade smallint (15) not null,
cpf numeric(11) not null,
cidade varchar(30) not null,
salario numeric(10) not null,
primary key (idcodf)
);

create table consultas(
data date not null,
hora time not null,
idcodm int(15)  not null,
idcodp int(15)  not null,
foreign key (idcodm) references medicos (idcodm),
foreign key (idcodp) references pacientes (idcodp)
);
```

Comment: Tem algum insert?

Comment: Sempre coloque o ERRO COMPLETO, assim facilita as buscas.

Comment: Por que não usa o workbench pra criar as tabelas e as chaves, não vejo as `CONSTRAINT`, parece que tentou fazer na mão a modelagem.

Comment: @clara você testou a minha resposta? Pois eu executei o comando completo e rodou sem erros em meu banco. Se funcionar, aceite a resposta como válida.

Answer (score 1):

Faltou o `unsigned` nos campos de chave estrangeira da `tabela` `consulta`

```
-- 1 --
create database clinica;
use clinica;

-- 2 --
create table ambulatorio(
idnroa int(15) unsigned not null auto_increment,
andar int(15) not null,
capacidade smallint(45) not null,
primary key (idnroa)
);

create table medicos(
idcodm int(15) unsigned not null auto_increment,
idnroa int(15) unsigned not null ,
nome varchar(40) not null,
idade smallint(15) not null,
especialidade char(20)  not null,
cpf numeric(11) not null,
cidade varchar(30) not null,
nroa int(15) not null, 
primary key (idcodm),
foreign key (idnroa) references ambulatorio (idnroa)
);

create table pacientes(
idcodp int(15) unsigned not null auto_increment,
nome varchar(40) not null,
idade smallint(15) not null,
cidade char(30) not null,
cpf numeric(11) not null,
primary key (idcodp)
);

create table funcionarios(
idcodf int(15) unsigned not null auto_increment,
nome varchar(40) not null,
idade smallint (15) not null,
cpf numeric(11) not null,
cidade varchar(30) not null,
salario numeric(10) not null,
primary key (idcodf)
);

create table consultas(
data date not null,
hora time not null,
idcodm int(15) Unsigned not null,
idcodp int(15) Unsigned not null,
foreign key (idcodm) references medicos (idcodm),
foreign key (idcodp) references pacientes (idcodp)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisar usar o Unsigned na sua tabela *consultas*

```
create table consultas(
data date not null,
hora time not null,
idcodm int(15) Unsigned not null,
idcodp int(15) Unsigned not null,
foreign key (idcodm) references medicos (idcodm),
foreign key (idcodp) references pacientes (idcodp)
);
```